# Display variable from $_POST in email when using an array

Tags: php, mailer

I am trying to get the results of a form that uses a check box for multiple selections.  I used an array as discussed on several other questions, but when i send the variables results through email it only gives me the last result selected.  I am sure I have the wrong code for displaying the variable.

**Code View:**

```
$assembly = $_POST['assembly'];
$pump = $_POST['pump'];
$exchanger = $_POST['exchanger'];
**if(!empty($_POST['options'])) {
foreach($_POST['options'] as $options) {
        echo $options; 
}
}**

$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$info = $_POST['info'];

$body = <<<EOD
<br><hr><br>
Assembly: $assembly <br>
Pump: $pump <br>
Heat Exchanger: $exchanger <br>
**Unit Options: $options <br>**
Email: $email <br>
Name: $name <br>
Info: $info <br>
```

Comment: Can you show the checkbox code (on the form)?

Comment: Using sixeightzero's suggestion of implode, i got it to work.  I had options[] as the name on the form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest the use of `implode`. Saves you a few line of code, and is not as stressful as the foreach:

```
$options = implode(", ", $_POST['options']);
Unit Options: $options <br>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
**if(!empty($_POST['options'])) {
foreach($_POST['options'] as $options) {
        echo $options; 
}
}**
```

You're not actually assigning anything to `$options` here, just printing it out. You're getting the last option showing up in the email because the variable you're setting in the loop retains its value.

Try:

```
$myOptions = "";

if(!empty($_POST['options'])) {
    foreach($_POST['options'] as $options) {
        $myOptions .= $options; 
    }
}
```

And then:

```
Unit Options: $myOptions <br>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this in place of your code.

```
$assembly = $_POST['assembly'];
$pump = $_POST['pump'];
$exchanger = $_POST['exchanger'];

$opt = "";
if(!empty($_POST['options'])) {
    foreach($_POST['options'] as $options) {
        $opt .= $options.",";
    }
    $opt = rtrim($opt, ","); //comma-separated checkbox values
}

$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$info = $_POST['info'];

$body = <<<EOD
<br><hr><br>
Assembly: $assembly <br>
Pump: $pump <br>
Heat Exchanger: $exchanger <br>
Unit Options: $opt <br>
Email: $email <br>
Name: $name <br>
Info: $info <br>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use

```
$option=''; 

   if(!empty($_POST['options'])) {
            $option = implode(',', $_POST['options']);
    }
```

try this

```
$assembly = $_POST['assembly'];
$pump = $_POST['pump'];
$exchanger = $_POST['exchanger'];
$option = "";
if(!empty($_POST['options'])) {
    $option = implode(',', $_POST['options']);
}
$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$info = $_POST['info'];

$body = <<<EOD
<br><hr><br>
Assembly: $assembly <br>
Pump: $pump <br>
Heat Exchanger: $exchanger <br>
Unit Options: $option <br>
Email: $email <br>
Name: $name <br>
Info: $info <br>
```